# How to validate if user already enroll a course in php

Tags: php, sql, validation, pdo

```
       if (isset($_POST['enroll'])) {
            $student_id       =  intval($session->user_id);
            $course_id      =  $course_id;
            $date       =   date('Y-m-d');
```

I need PDO function that returns false if user course_id already exists.

```
    ***if ($enroll->student_id has this->course_id) {
           $message = "<b>U already enrolled continue</b>";
    }else{***
                $enroll->user_id   = $user_id;
                $enroll->course_id  = $course_id;
                $enroll->en_date    = $date;
                $enroll->create();
//            }
```

**This is my Students table columns**

1. std_id
2. first_name

**An this is my courses table**

1. course_id
2. course_name

**I also have Enroll table**

1. id
2. student_id
3. course_id

I need to Validate if user already taken a course using PHP PDO function
Also number of students taken specific course .

Comment: You need to add some code to the question. Are you asking for the SQL queries to get what you need or the PDO code to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below function to check if user already enroll or not.

```
function user_enroll($student_id, $course_id){
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE student_id=? AND course_id=?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $student_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $course_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row)
{
    return false; // course already taken
}
return true; // course not taken

}
```

To do both thing like return user enroll or not and also total number students enrolled in specify course.

```
function user_enroll($student_id, $course_id){
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE student_id=? AND course_id=?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $student_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $course_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total_enrolled_students = $pdo->query('select count(*) from enroll WHERE course_id='.$course_id)->fetchColumn(); 
$ret_data = array('user_enroll' => true,'total_std_enrolled'=>$total_enrolled_students);

if($row)
{
    $ret_data['user_enroll'] = false;
    return $ret_data; // course already taken
}
return $ret_data; // course not taken
```

So this function return array with two element. One is **user_enroll** which is for student enrolled or not and other is **total_std_enrolled** which is for total number of students in course.

Comment: How will this give you number-of-students per course? Secondly, as a best practice, should never do *, instead fetch the required column. * is always a heavy query.

Comment: you want to return total number of students for given course in above function or another functions to return total number of students per course ?

Comment: The question mentions `if user already taken a course` and `number of students taken specific course`

Answer (score 1):

This query will verify if the student has enrolled for the mentioned course:

```
SELECT id FROM enrolled_table WHERE student_id = STUDENT_ID_PARAMETER and course_id = COURSE_ID_PARAMETER
```

And this query will give you number of students per course:

```
SELECT count(id), course_id FROM enrolled_table
WHERE student_id not null
GROUP BY course_id
ORDER BY count(id) DESC;
```